Choose which model manager to use when doing prefetch_related?
I have a Product model in my Django app, which uses a custom model manager where all the prefetch_related statements are made:
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .select_related("core_product")
            .prefetch_related("images")
            .prefetch_related("bundled_products")
        )

class Product(models.Model):
    _base_manager = ProductManager
    objects = ProductManager()

    # ... model fields

This works fine; when I use the ORM and within the Admin the custom manager is used, preventing a whole bunch of duplicate queries.
The problem is when I have another model that has a prefetch_related to the Product model: it now inherits all the prefetch_related from the Product, even though that's not necessary. It causes a whole bunch of unnecessary queries to be made.
class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .select_related("flag")
            .prefetch_related("condition_products")
            .prefetch_related("limited_to_users")
            .order_by("-priority")
        )

Here the condition_products field is that Product model from above, and just by including this prefetch_related, all of its prefetch_related statements are also inherited. How can I prevent this from happening? Can I specify which object manager to use in the prefetch_related - so that is uses a "bare" manager?

just a side note, you override the bare manager objects in your class.

Yes, so that when I do Product.objects.all() in a view, I automatically get the correct prefetches applied. But yeah maybe I shouldn't do this, use another name and use that in my views.

Have you considered adding a bare manager using something like bare_manager = models.Manager() to the Product class?

I have, but then the question is still: how do you make sure that that bare_manager is used by the prefetch_related?

Can you remove that _base_manager attribute from your class? Your manager should already be set as the default manager is there a reason you want to use it as a base manager as well? Also note instead of setting that attribute directly the more correct way to set the base manager would be to set base_manager_name on the models Meta.

Add a simple manager to the Product:
class Product(models.Model):
    _base_manager = ProductManager
    objects = ProductManager()
    _simple_manager = models.Manager()
and then use this manager with a Prefetch object [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .select_related('flag')
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('condition_products', Product._simple_manager.all()),
                'limited_to_users',
            )
            .order_by('-priority')
        )

Quick question: From my understanding prefetching would be done through the base manager, is that correct? Looking at OPs description I don't really see a need for them to set a base manager, their use case seems to fit the default manager instead.

The base manager is used by the Admin. Without those prefetches the Admin does a crazy amount of queries and is noticeably slower

@AbdulAzizBarkat: given I understand it correctly, he wants to set the _base_manager, such that for the ModelAdmin and all that, it automatically also preteches (although that is more a guess). But yes, it uses by default the _base_manager: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L156

@KevinRenskers: you can use get_queryset() in the admin though and thus there direct to the proper manager. :)

@KevinRenskers I thought the admin uses the default manager. Maybe I got that wrong.

@AbdulAzizBarkat: it does: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L435 but that defaults in its turn to the _base_manager :) I think two parts of the documentation that is lacking and quite useful is what managers handle what, and how you can create queries with a "cascade" of lookups. These seem to be a bit nebulous.

willem is correct: I want the admin to automatically prefetch everything, without having to override the queryset for every ModelAdmin.

First I went with the solution from willeM_ Van Onsem, with a _simple_manager, and then using that _simple_manager in the prefetch_related. But in the end I turned it around: the default manager is the normal one, and I use a custom one that has the prefetch_related statements. In my views I now explicitly use the custom manager, everything else by default uses the normal manager. Seems a bit clearer than sometimes having to override the manager used in the prefetch_related statements.
class Product(models.Model):
    _base_manager = ProductManager
    objects = models.Manager()
    prefetched_objects = ProductManager()

